# CAN NOT INSTALL HOMEBREW

Tags: homebrew

MacBook-Pro:~ Carina$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" -bash: curl: command not found -bash: ruby: command not found How can I fix that, because I am trying to download pygame on my mac, Please help me!! Thank you very much!

Comment: For your next questions please, go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) then read  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask a Question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Try this commands:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/bin/curl-wrapper

sudo mv /usr/bin/curl.bin /usr/bin/curl
```

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105730/curl-command-cant-be-found-osx-utilities-have-been-replaced-by-gnu-coreutils